# Linq sorting, grouping, and returning a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have an array of custom objects (PONO) called FrameList, I can orderBy and GroupBy to sort and group. But now I want to return a dictionary, and I am getting the error:

**(BTW, there is no error is I remove the .ToDictionary() method. )**

> Error 1   'System.Linq.IGrouping' does
>   not contain a definition for 'type' and no extension method 'type'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Linq.IGrouping' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\ysg4206\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\Watson\CatalogServiceClasses\BuildToby.cs   21  38  Watson

Here is the snippet that sorts and groups:

```
    var dict = request.FrameList.OrderBy(f => f.trueDate)
        .GroupBy(f => f.type)
        .ToDictionary(f => f.type, f => f);
```

and here is the definition of the FrameList (which is a simple array of FrameData)

```
[DataContract]
public class FrameData
{
    [DataMember]
    public String idx { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String path { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String date { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime trueDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `.ToDictionary(f => f.Key, f => f)` The IGrouping will group the elements by type into the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do.

If you're just looking to create an idiomatic multi-map, try:

```
var lookup = request.FrameList.ToLookup(f => f.type);
```

If you're looking to create a multi-map with the `Dictionary` class, try:

```
var dict = request.FrameList
                  .GroupBy(f => f.type)
                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Do note that in both of these cases, `OrderBy` before grouping is useless since Lookup and Dictionary are inherently unordered collections. If you're trying to accomplish something with your ordering (perhaps you want items within a group to be ordered by date?), please clarify, and we might be able to provide something more appropriate.

EDIT: Based on your comment, looks like you need:

```
var dict = request.FrameList
                  .GroupBy(f => f.type)
                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, 
                                g => g.OrderBy(f => f.trueDate)
                                      .ToList());
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thank you. The OrderBy is needed not to sort the groups (or the dictonary elements) but rather that the List that is at each Key, be a sorted list (by date). And this does the  trick.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your method signature is `IDictionary<string,IList<FrameData>>`

Try to use next code snippet:

```
var dict = request.FrameList
    .OrderBy(f => f.trueDate)
    .GroupBy(f => f.type)
    .ToDictionary(f => f.Key, f => f.ToList());
```

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I was confused by the comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

GroupBy operator returns [IGrouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) objects. Those objects have `Key` property. But there is no `type` property on grouping object (its property of your entity):

```
 var dict = request.FrameList
        .OrderBy(f => f.trueDate)
        .GroupBy(f => f.type) // this selects IEnumerable<IGrouping>
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g);
```

NOTE: If this is a Linq to Entities query, then `GroupBy` returns `IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>`